# Finding the equation of a line joining A and B

Tags: geometry

I have the question "Find the equation of the line joining A and B, giving your answer in the form ax + by + c = 0 where a, b and c are integers."

From the previous question the point A has coordinates (1,5) and point B (-2,3) and I worked out the gradient to be 2/3.

The final answer I get is:

2X - 3Y + 13 = 0,

Is this correct ?

Comment: Since there is only one line joining the two points, you can easily check whether your equation is correct by checking that the two original points lie on the line i.e. that their co-ordinates satisfy the equation you have found.

Comment: So would you use the points for A or B ? Thanks.

Comment: e.g. $2(1)-3(5)+13=0$

Comment: Thanks yes this is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the slope of your equation is given by $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{5-3}{2+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$ thus we get
$$y=\frac{2}{3}x+n$$ and $$5=\frac{2}{3}+n$$ therefore $$y=\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{13}{3}$$

Comment: Yes but x2 is -2 not -1 ?

Comment: yes this is right,just corrected